# Ruby on Rails Compatibility error. mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffi

While running rails c , I am getting the following error.

> /Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:145:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library '/Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/http-parser-1.2.1/ext/arm-darwin/libhttp-parser-ext.bundle': dlopen(/Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/http-parser-1.2.1/ext/arm-darwin/libhttp-parser-ext.bundle, 0x0005): tried: '/Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/http-parser-1.2.1/ext/arm-darwin/libhttp-parser-ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/http-parser-1.2.1/ext/arm-darwin/libhttp-parser-ext.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/poombavai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/http-parser-1.2.1/ext/arm-darwin/libhttp-parser-ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) (LoadError)

Tried installing ffi using arm64 with the following command,

```
arch -arm64 gem install ffi --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries
```

But it did not help.

I am running these on Apple M1 Pro chip.
Kindly advise.